# Explanation for a Regex

Tags: regex

Can anyone please explain me what this regex signifies?

```
/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think this regex will validate the IPV4 address

Please use this link to get explation of your regex

## [Regex Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

```
    NODE                     EXPLANATION
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                        the beginning of the string
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \1:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1                        '1'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        2                        '2'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-4]                    any character of: '0' to '4'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        25                       '25'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \1
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \2 (3 times):
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .                        any character except \n
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        (                        group and capture to \3:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          1                        '1'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          2                        '2'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-4]                    any character of: '0' to '4'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          25                       '25'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of \3
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ){3}                     end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                               quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                               repetition of the captured pattern will be
                               stored in \2)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                               string
```

Comment: does it match an IP address?

Comment: @csmckelvey Yes i think it validate IPv4 address

Comment: I don't know, but you just made debugging all this garbage PHP script I'm decoding a breeze.... THANK YOU!. Total upvote for the link in comments.

Comment: I'd be careful claiming that this "*validates IPv4 addresses*".  First, we're obviously only dealing with IPv4 addresses that are in dotted-decimal format (but that's a rather pedantic point). Second, it *won't* validate any address whose first octet is `0x00` yet *will* validate other reserved addresses: one would need to consider what implications this has on one's application. Third, it *won't* validate values that have superfluous leading zeroes. Finally (and quite obviously), regex being only a string pattern match, this doesn't verify that the address is actually correct or in use.

Answer (score 5):

While the answer above explains the regex atom by atom, I think the answer that you're looking for is "it matches IPv4 addresses."

To wit:

```
# Match the beginning of a string
/^  
# Match a number from 1-255
([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
# Same as above with a . in front of it
(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))
# Match the above three times.
{3}
# Match end of the string
$/
```

Answer (score 4):

It is look like an expression which accepts values from `1.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`

**A better explanation :**

[image]

[**Meaning**](http://regex101.com/r/yP0oS6)

[image]

Comment: I am more interesting on how you generate the chart?